# Multiclassification: precision-recall from scratch vs sklearn

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, supervised-learning, precision-recall, multi-class

I would like to know if there´s any issue behind using `sklearn`'s `precision/recall` metric functions and coding up from scratch in a `multiclass` classification task. I noticed some researchers  go by implementing this from scratch (multiclass) when it is clear such experience researcher cannot be unaware of `sklearn`'s provided functions.

For example in [this](https://github.com/sinadabiri/Transport-Mode-GPS-CNN/blob/master/CNN-Keras.py), a 5-class classification task. The research calculates precision and recall like so:

```
Pred = model.predict(Test_X, batch_size=32)
Pred_Label = np.argmax(Pred, axis=1)

ActualPositive = []
for i in range(NoClass):
    AA = np.where(Test_Y_ori == i)[0]
    ActualPositive.append(AA)

PredictedPositive = []
for i in range(NoClass):
    AA = np.where(Pred_Label == i)[0]
    PredictedPositive.append(AA)

TruePositive = []
FalsePositive = []
for i in range(NoClass):
    AA = []
    BB = []
    for j in PredictedPositive[i]:
        if Pred_Label[j] == Test_Y_ori[j]:
            AA.append(j)
        else:
            BB.append(j)
    TruePositive.append(AA)
    FalsePositive.append(BB)
Precision = []
Recall = []
for i in range(NoClass):
    Precision.append(len(TruePositive[i]) * 1./len(PredictedPositive[i]))
    Recall.append(len(TruePositive[i]) * 1./len(ActualPositive[i]))
```

When he could probably use:

```
sklearn.metrics.precision_score(y_true, y_pred,..)
sklearn.metrics.recall_score(y_true, y_pred,...)
```

But the researcher computes `confusion matrix` using scikit-learn API like so:

```
ConfusionM = confusion_matrix(list(Test_Y_ori), Pred_Label, labels=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: The best way to obtain a reliable answer to "why someone did something" is to ask the person directly. Here we could only make guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is much easier to implement directly. A situation whereby no functionality from `sklearn` is used, so it is too much a dependency to have large library just for confusion matrix.

If you would like to compute confusion matrix for multi-classifier, that is no more than a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table).

Let's use a synthetic data, 100 prediction and true classes, and compute confusion matrix with pandas cross-tabulation method with normalising over columns, i.e., diagonals of the resulting matrix will give recall but more accurate naming would be `Top-1` score while recall/fall-out has only a connotation for binary classifiers. Here is the sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
classes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
np.random.seed(42)
predicted_classes = np.random.choice(classes, 100)
true_classes = np.random.choice(classes, 100)
# recall: Top-1 scores
confusion_matrix_column_normalized = pd.crosstab(predicted_classes, true_classes, normalize='columns')
np.diag(confusion_matrix_column_normalized)
# Top-1 scores a = 0.15, b = 0.40, c=0.17, d=0.29
```

Please note that we use `predicted_classes` as first argument
on `pd.crosstab`, while we want to group over predicted classes.

There are some discussions on how to form confusion matrix, see wikipedia discussion [transposed confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Confusion_matrix#Confusion_Matrix_is_Transposed_compared_to_standard_practice), so depending on the field naming of recall and precision may reversed.