# Cross validation for one-vs-all classifiers

Tags: cross-validation

I have input data that I need to assign to one of the five classes A,B,..., E, I know which of the five classes will be around, it could be A and B, A and B and E or anything else. In a preprocessing step, I summarise multiple occurrences of a class into a feature. So each feature in the candidate list can appear at most once. I need to make sure that the assignement of the input is one of the classes which are actually present.

To tackle this goal, I decided to use One-vs-all classifiers.

For a given input, each class A-E will tell me how likely it is that this data is associated with itself.

So the actual prediction is comprised of two layers: by class, predict the probability of the input belonging to it, and choose the one with highest probability.

Example:

Input 1: belongs to A, has candidates A, C, E

so if there was only one feature, one example to predict would look like this:

```
id, target, class, feature
1, A, A, 1
1, A, C, 1
1, A, E, 1
```

Input 2: belongs to B, has candidates B, D

Input 3: belongs to C, has candidates A, B, C, D

For training a classifier for e.g. A, my approach is to choose all training data examples where A is in the class, and assign all examples where the target is not A to "other".

so for the examples:

```
id, target, class, feature
1, A, A, 1
3, other, A, 2
```

However, since this a "stacked" classifier, how do I approach cross validation? Do I need to grid-search and optimize all of the 5 classifiers? Which metrics do I choose for evaluation? (typically, A will be the target for class A much less than "other")?
How do I ensure that in every CV step I train all classes?
How do I predict on folds overall if the CV for one class selects "arbitrary" rows?

Please let me know if I should clarify on the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You could do a "standard" CV, hyper-parameter optimization and evaluation on the 'stacked'-model with "standard" splits. Consider the 'stacked'-model as a meta-model, i.e., function with parameters to your 5-classifiers that live inside the function. Those 5 classifiers are called within that meta-function depending on the label during training or selecting the highest probability during prediction/testing.

For evaluation, use `Top-1` score, see recent post on this: [top-1 evaluation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/530438) .